# alphabet split instead of word split using lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so ive predefined a set of names in a list(lst1) and when the user inputs a name,which doesnt matches the ones in the pre defined list prints a message which returns the element which didnt match along with a message "doesnt belong to our family" but when i run this code, the name gets split into a list like for example instead of "Abby:doesnt belong to our family",it prints "a":doesnt belong...."b":doesnt belong and so on...

heres the code:

```
lst1=['john','undertaker','kane','randy']
a1=input().strip()
a=a1.split(',')

user_input=[str(i) for i in a]

for _input in user_input:
    for name in [str(i) for i in str(_input)]:
        if name not in lst1:
            print(f"{name}:Not in family")
```

sample input:
1)Rey mysteiro
2)Randy

output:
1)rey mysterio
r:Not in family
e:Not in family
y:Not in family
 :Not in family
m:Not in family
y:Not in family
s:Not in family
t:Not in family
e:Not in family
r:Not in family
i:Not in family
o:Not in family

2)randy
r:Not in family
a:Not in family
n:Not in family
d:Not in family
y:Not in family

for some reason this is not working ,any suggestions to improve this code as well as tackle this problem is appreciated!Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
user_input=[str(i) for i in a]
```

is unnecessary, items in `a` are already strings. And so is this:

```
for name in [str(i) for i in str(_input)]:
```

(this is the part that turns your word from `_input` into a list of letters).
Correct way of doing this:

```
lst1 = ['john','undertaker','kane','randy']
user_input = input().strip().split(',')
for name in user_input:
    if name not in lst1:
        print(f"{name}:Not in family")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
lst1=['john','undertaker','kane','randy'] #use a set instead of a list.
lst1=set(lst1)
user_names=input().split(',')
for user in user_names:
    if user not in lst1: #now for checking membership it takes O(1)  but with list it's O(N)
         print(f'{user} : Not part of the family')
```

---

`user_input=[str(i) for i in a]` this is redundant `i` is already `str`.

`for name in [str(i) for i in str(_input)]` is step is why you get individual alphabets.

`_input` is a string.Let's say `_input` is `'randy'`. When you do `for name in [str(i) in str(_input)]` which is equivalent to this `for name in ['r','a','n','d','y']`. And `str(_input)` is redundant `_input` is already string and `str(i)` is also redundant as `i` is already string.